# Add many IPs to Azure NSG rule

Tags: azure, powershell

I have Azure NSG. inside i have a rule called "Blocked_IP"
I need to automate the process of updating this rule once a day with thousands of new ips (Azure max ip per rule is 4k)

looking at the documentaiton i have 2 possible commands:

```
$ipsarry = Get-Content .\file.txt
az network nsg rule update -g $groupName --nsg-name $NSGName -n $ruleName --source-address-prefix $ipsarry
```

file.txt will hold the ips. this will work as long file.txt hold aprox less than 500 ips, as if i add more the command will be a very very long string and there will be an exception.
i cannot add this in parts as i cannot find a way to append the data, upon each call the old data is deleted.

using the other command

```
$NSG = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name 'test' -ResourceGroupName 'Testik'


$Params = @{
  'Name'                     = 'auto_farm_protection4'
  'NetworkSecurityGroup'     = $NSG
  'Protocol'                 = 'TCP'
  'Direction'                = 'Inbound'
  'Priority'                 = 500
  'SourceAddressPrefix'      = "1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2"
  'SourcePortRange'          = '*'
  'DestinationAddressPrefix' = '*'
  'DestinationPortRange'     = 3389
  'Access'                   = 'Deny'
}

Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig @Params | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
```

will give me the same problem.

looks like google doesnt help me much.  any help would be great.

Comment: "aprox less than 500 ips" - 500 prefixes (`1.1.1.0/24, ...`) or 500 individual IPs (`1.1.1.1, ...`)?

Comment: 500 individual ips, i need to add aprox 3.5-3.8k individual

Comment: What is the use-case here?  It seems like it would be easier to define an allow-list to let in the good IP addresses instead of constantly adding to the deny-list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name <String> -NetworkSecurityGroup <PSNetworkSecurityGroup> -SourceAddressPrefix String[]` .
Load the ip address from the text file into String Array (i guess you have a delimiter separating the ip address). Finally, pass it to  the parameter of **SourceAddressPrefix** .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/set-aznetworksecurityruleconfig?view=azps-6.6.0

Comment: Thank you problem is there's a limit to the string[] and it is much smaller than the allowed ip's, currently approx 50 ips can be sent in a single command and max ip is 4k